# Using includes with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can you use es6 includes on an array of objects?

Object

```
const classes = [{name: 'test', active: true}, {name: 'test', active: false}]
```

es6

```
classes.includes(myClass => myClass.active === true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`includes` looks for a specific value passed.

If you want to test whether at least one value passes a test, use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

`classes.some(myClass => myClass.active === true);`

---

***Edit:*** To answer the actual question in the title, i.e. could you do something like:

`classes.includes({name: 'test', active: true});`

also no.

[`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) does a `===` check<sup>†</sup>, which objects do not pass in JavaScript.

<sup>†</sup> [Except for `NaN`](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/issues/29) which will return true if included.